# HTTPRequest not working

Tags: php, html, ajax, httpwebrequest

I have the following code but my `<a onclick="meldaan()">Aanmelden</a>` isn't working. The function doesn't get called.

This is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function meldaan()
{
    var voornaam = document.getElementById('voornaam').value;
    var achternaam = document.getElementById('achternaam').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","aanmelden.php?naam=" + encodeURIComponent(voornaam) + "&achternaam=" + encodeURIComponent(achternaam) + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email) + "&password=" 
    + encodeURIComponent(password),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

I have the function placed in my header.php file which is included in the footer.php (the place where `<a onclick="meldaan()">Aanmelden</a>` is located.

What am I doing wrong?

The results are properly deliverd to my page because I tried echoing something and it did show up, so it must be in this code.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semicolon:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
       ^------ HERE
```